# Can not Install sharp

Tags: npm, sharp

sharp@0.18.4 install C:\Users\hp\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\sharp

`node-gyp rebuild`

```
C:\Users\hp\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\sharp>if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )  else (node "" rebuild )
Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel build, please add the "/m" switch.
MSBUILD : error MSB4132: The tools version "2.0" is unrecognized. Available tools versions are "4.0".
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\msbuild.exe` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:258:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:198:12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.10240
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\hp\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\sharp
gyp ERR! node -v v8.9.3
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.6.2
gyp ERR! not ok
npm WARN Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rmdir 'C:\Users\hp\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules'
npm WARN  { Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rmdir 'C:\Users\hp\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules'
npm WARN   stack: 'Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rmdir \'C:\\Users\\hp\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\'',
npm WARN   errno: -4048,
npm WARN   code: 'EPERM',
npm WARN   syscall: 'rmdir',
npm WARN   path: 'C:\\Users\\hp\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules' }
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! sharp@0.18.4 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the sharp@0.18.4 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\hp\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2017-12-27T19_25_54_261Z-debug.log
```

Answer (score 4):

the easiest way to install sharp on windows OS is to use the following npm package 
which is called [windows-build-tools](https://www.npmjs.com/package/windows-build-tools)

```
npm install --global --production windows-build-tools
```

this as npm says it downloads

> installs Visual C++ Build Tools, provided free of charge by Microsoft. These tools are required to compile popular native modules. It will also install Python 2.7, configuring your machine and npm appropriately.

after this `npm install sharp`