# Always fail when npm install something

Tags: npm, npm-install

When I try to run `npm install`, I always have the following error:

```
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! sharp@0.18.4 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the sharp@0.18.4 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\hauph\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-04-16T04_45_21_160Z-debug.log
```

Can anyone please tell me what's wrong and how to fix it so that I can run `npm install` normally?

My node version: **10.16.3**

My npm version: **6.9.0**

Thank you!

Comment: you can check for detailed error msg in this file;
C:\Users\hauph\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-04-16T04_45_21_160Z-debug.log

Comment: Can you check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47987435/can-not-install-sharp